# Browser specific session management

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, web-applications, session-management

Let me explain my scenario,

I have created a spring web application and deployed on tomcat. Then I opened a chrome browser and launched the application. It run successfully. Then again I have opened a new Browser lets say IE/Firefox. Then again I relaunched my application on it. Then the session available at Chrome browser should be invalidated or redirected to Login page. In simple way, I should be able access my web page in one browser at a time.

Is there any way to achieve this using spring ?? or any other way ??

Thanks
Naveen

Comment: I doubt if Java-EE provides any mechanism for it.  I suggest you use a persistent data mechanism to store the state, and if there is another request from the same IP or User, you can invalidate the session from the other browser.
Of course, the state will have to be pushed to the earlier browser.

Comment: HTTP is a stateless protocol.  You could keep a record of login/user-agent pairs and then know if a user logged in from a different browser.  What about the same Browser on a different machine?

Comment: Spring Security lets you limit the number of concurrent sessions per user.

Comment: @Scary Wombat : Thank you for your inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not say how you do your authentication. But as you are allready using Spring, I would advice you to use also Spring security that has configurable session management out of the box.

Using html config, you can ask that a new session invalidate a previous from same user with (extract from Spring Security Reference Manual 3.2.x / Security Namespace Configuration / Advanced Web Features / Session Management) :

```
<http>
  ...
  <session-management>
     <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" />
  </session-management>
</http>
```

or that a new session will fail with :

```
<http>
  ...
  <session-management>
     <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" />
  </session-management>
</http>
```

Comment: @SergeBallesta : Thanks for the explanation. It works for the same user concept. But how about different users concept ??

Comment: You really want only one session at a time independently of the logged user ? That is, if there is an active session for userA and userB logs into the application the session of userA should be invalidated ?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is not something out of box Java [**Web Container**](http://java.dzone.com/articles/what-servlet-container) functionality. But this still can be achievable using some application logic. Here is one way to achieve this:

1. Create a **filter** which stores the **mapping of username as key and corresponding session id** in some map (You can also use database for this); In case you use map, make sure you use [`ConcurrentHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html).
2. Add this filter **after the Authentication Filter**.
3. This filter will be invoked for **all the URLs**.
4. Whenever a user login is requested, this filter will simply add/overwrite the mapping of the username and current session id.
5. For the all the other request (non-login), the filter will simply check if the **current session id is same as the one stored** in the map against the username. If yes then proceed, else invalidate the session (as user has done another login indicated by different session id) and redirect user with appropriate message.